# Setting logger properties programatically to show hibernate queries

Tags: java, hibernate, java.util.logging

I'm using `Hibernate` and `java.util.Logger` class for logs in my project. I have a separate config file for both. I am able to switch between showing and not showing SQL queries by setting `org.hibernate.SQL.level` property to `ALL` in the **log configuration file**, but I can't figure out how to do it programatically (I want to handle this through run parameters but without having to use two seperate log configuration files).

So far I have tried setting this parameter in hibernate `Configuration` class, to no avail (properties are getting set, I double checked, but no queries show up).

Then I figured it must be handled by `Logger` class itself, but `LogManager` does not have any methods for setting a property. Browsing through the web guided me towards `FileHandler` class but I am able to set only the 'usual' log properties (like `pattern`, `level`, etc).

Does it mean I'm wrong in thinking I have to change the `Logger` class and it should in fact be set in hibernate's `Configuration`? If that's the case, why did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

> ...I can't figure out how to do it programmatically (I want to handle this through run parameters but without having to use two separate log configuration files).

I would have assumed that the current situation solved the problem as log configurations are set using a run-time parameter.  That said, the general approach is to get and store a strong reference to the logger and change the properties of that logger.

```
private static final Logger hardRef = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
static {
    if (traceSql()) {
        hardRef.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    }
}

private static boolean traceSql() {
    return true; //@todo Add code.
}
```